# Elixir: How to Watch a Public Directory for Change?

Tags: javascript, laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

I have some random html files in my public directory that I use in a Laravel project. Since I work with them I'd like to reload the browser, every time I make a change to these files.

Is this possible, if yes how?

Putting something like this in my Laravel gulpfile might be the right direction:

```
.task('reload', 'public/elements/**')
```

Which then would trigger the according task maybe:

```
gulp.task('reload', function () {
     gulp.src('public/**/*.html')
        .pipe(refresh()); // this does not work
});
```

---

Also it seems that browserSync has a solution here: https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/#option-files

But it doesn't work on my machine (windows 7).

Comment: Are you wanting it to refresh your web browser, like FireFox?

Comment: yes, I want to refresh my browser.

Comment: I gave an attempt at answering your question with documentation. If it's not working let me know and I'll try sorting it out. Had no idea Gulp could do that.

Answer (score 1):

I thought your question was insane but I second-guessed myself and looked it up.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/elixir#browser-sync

I'm not sure what the requirements of this are. I know for sure I was unable to use `notify-send` until I switched my DE from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 16.04, so you might not have any luck unless you are using a supported environment.

Here is a complete list of options.

https://www.browsersync.io/docs/options/

From the looks of it, I would try this:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.browserSync({
        files: ["public/elements/*"]
    });
});
```

Comment: This seems to be the solution, theoretically. But it doesn't work on my machine (windows7) and can't swith at the moment. Sad.

Comment: Bummer! I literally just this week switched to Ubuntu 16.04 from Windows 7 and it's a lot less dramatic than you think. Whenever you get a chance you should definitely just dive right in. Though make sure your browsersync is on so you don't have to reset 100 passwords, lol

Comment: I'll make the switch to Apple in a month. Saving up for a MacBook Pro 15. Would like to give you the right answer btw, but since it does not work in my case, it would be misleading to everyone else with the same problem.